# Variable en un array

Tags: php, mercadopago, mercadolibre

Tengo esta api en cual trabaja con array y le quiero pasar un valor que se define en una variable y no lo toma, pero tampoco me arroja ningun error:

```
<?php
include 'include/cont_db.php';
require_once ('sdk-mercadopago/lib/mercadopago.php');

$code = '5LGIm61xtGES';

$ress = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM reservas WHERE code = '".$code."'");
$row = $ress->fetch();

$valor = (float)$row['valor']; //covierte dato de valor string a num

$cliente_id = "numero";
$cliente_secret = "numeros";

$mp = new MP($cliente_id, $cliente_secret);

$preference_data = array(
"items" => array(
    array(
        "title" => "Pago de Reserva",
        "quantity" => 1,
        "currency_id" => "ARS",
        "unit_price" => $valor //velor en pesos
    )
)
);

$preference = $mp->create_preference($preference_data);
?>
<h3><a href="<?php echo $preference['response']['init_point']; ?>">Pay</a></h3>
```

Si creo una variable con el nombre `titulo` y reemplazo el texo, funciona bien, pero no me pasa lo mismo con el valor.

---

[Solucion]

Gracias un amigo, entendi que el numero que el valor que estaba pasando era de valor `string` y `"unit_price"` debe ser un valor numerico, por eso el link de pago no se generaba correctamente. La solucion fue convertir el valor `string` a `num` de la variable `$valor` haciendo un typecast a `(float)`:

```
$valor = (float) $row['valor']; //covierte dato de valor string a num
```

Comment: de donde llega y que valor tiene `$row[....]`

Comment: llega de un `select`; `$ress = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM reserver WHERE code = '".$rescode."'");`, `$row = $ress->fetch();`

Comment: El código funciona sin problemas cambiado `$valor = $row['totalpesos'];` por `$valor = 1400;`, por lo que el error está en alguna otra parte del código. Asegúrate de que no hay ningún error en la consulta a la base de datos,  y comparte el log del servidor para poder ayudarte mejor (o añade algo de código que te muestre los errores). Lee sobre cómo crear un [mcve] para más información.

Comment: Ahi lo actualice, igualmente sigue todo en blanco, no me trae el link para pagar

Comment: creo que `fetch` es una `array` y lo estoy agregando a otro `array` y eso no se como solucionarlo, porque cuando la variable `valor` cambia, deja de ser un `array`, el dato lo interpreta bien

Comment: `fetch` no es un array, es un método para leer los resultados de la consulta. Depura si la consulta trae datos, y cómo vendrían esos datos haciendo esto: **`var_dump($row);`**

Comment: gracias @A.Cedano, use` var_dump($valor)` y me arrojo este dato: `string(4) "1400" `, lo cual esta bien, pero no hace que pueda realizar el pago. Solo figura el texto

Comment: No sé que quieres decir con que *solo figura el texto*. Por si fuera un problema de tipos, puedes convertirlo a entero: **`$valor = (int) $row['valor'];`**

Comment: Entiendo lo que dices y ahora me da como resultado `1400`, probe haciendo esto: `print_r($row['valor'])` y me trae el valor que necesito, pero ahora el problema es que esta el valor solo y no con el link este: `<a href="<?php echo $preference['response']['init_point']; ?>">Pay</a>`

Comment: Pero ¿tú quieres mostrar el valor en ese link?

Comment: Claro, asi puede realizar el pago. Todo ese array hacer que tome los datos de la persona que reserva y trar el valor del mismo. Entonces se genera un link de pago con ese valor. Eso ya viene asi desde [MercadoPago](https://www.mercadopago.cl/developers/es/solutions/payments/basic-checkout/receive-payments/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es posible que lo que tienes en `"unit_price" => $valor //velor en pesos` esta errado, segun los comentarios pareciera que estas tratando de enviar una cadena en lugar de un entero. Haz un typecast `(float)` o `(int)` porque pareciera que la api esta esperando un valor de tipo entero/numerico.

Comment: Gracias @foursixnine por todo.